# Cant save my JtextFields in arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I try to implement a sign up form in Java. My Main frame consists of 3 buttons: Log in, Sign Up, Place Order which I have `setEnabled(false)`. If the user wants to log in (means he already owns an account) and he gives correct id and psw, I want the login frame to hide and my main frame to appear with button Place order enabled this time. This is my 1st problem. My second problem is upon Sign Up I can't save the user's input in an `ArrayList<User>`.

MainFrame.java:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JButton loginButton;
private JButton signUpButton;
 JButton placeOrderButton;

private boolean q;

private UserManager userManager;

public MainFrame(){
    super("Main Panel");
    userManager = new UserManager();
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.addActionListener(new LoginButtonListener());
    placeOrderButton = new JButton("Place Order");
    placeOrderButton.addActionListener(new PlaceOrderButtonListener());
    placeOrderButton.setEnabled(false);



    signUpButton = new JButton("Sign Up");
    signUpButton.addActionListener(new SignUpButtonListener());



    this.getContentPane().add(loginButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    this.getContentPane().add(signUpButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(placeOrderButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);






}

class LoginButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         new LoginFrame(userManager);

    }
}

class SignUpButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        new SignUpFrame(userManager);

    }
}


class PlaceOrderButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argO){



    }


}
```

User.java:

```
public class User {

private String fullName;
private String email;
private String userID;
private String password;

public User(String fullName, String email, String userID, String password) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.email = email;
    this.userID = userID;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}
public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

LoginFrame.java:

```
public class LoginFrame extends JFrame{

    private JButton loginButton;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField password;

    private UserManager userManager;

    public LoginFrame(UserManager userManager){
        super("Enter your credentials to login");
        this.userManager = userManager;
        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(new LoginButtonListener());

        usernameField = new JTextField(15);
        password = new JPasswordField(15);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Username:"));
        mainPanel.add(usernameField);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
        mainPanel.add(password);
        mainPanel.add(loginButton);

        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }           
        class LoginButtonListener implements ActionListener{


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String givenID = usernameField.getText();



    if(userManager.isUserInList(givenID)){
        String givenPass = password.getText();
        User theUser = userManager.getUserWithID(givenID);
        if(givenPass.equals(theUser.getPassword())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access granted!");

        dispose();

        new MainFrame();
        }


        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "Wrong Password", 
                            "Error!",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Wrong username", 
                "Error!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

}
```

SignUpFrame.java:

```
public class SignUpFrame extends JFrame{

private JButton signupButton;
private JTextField name;
private JTextField email;
private JTextField username;
private JPasswordField pass;

private UserManager userManager;

public SignUpFrame (UserManager userManager){
super("Please fill in your Data");

userManager = new UserManager();

signupButton = new JButton("Sign Up!");
signupButton.addActionListener(new signupButtonListener());

JTextField name = new JTextField(15);

JTextField email = new JTextField(15);

JTextField username = new JTextField(15);

JTextField pass = new JTextField(15);



JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
mainPanel.add(name);
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
mainPanel.add(email);
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
mainPanel.add(username);
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
mainPanel.add(pass);
mainPanel.add(signupButton);

this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
this.pack();
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);


class signupButtonListener implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



    User u2 = new User(name.getText(),email.getText(),username.getText(),pass.getText());



    add(u2);

}
}
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserManager {

```
private ArrayList<User> userList;

public UserManager(){
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    User u1 = new User("Teo Haik", "teo@uom.gr","teohaik","teopass");
    userList.add(u1);
}

public boolean isUserInList(String ID){
    for(User u: userList){
        if(u.getUserID().equals(ID)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public User getUserWithID(String ID){
    for(User u: userList){
        if(u.getUserID().equals(ID)){
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post your tried code please.

Comment: Post http://sscce.org/ to get quick help

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?You have problem to store data? or get data from fields?Whats the problem exactly *i cant save users input into arraylist* .. why? Reason? modify your question so we can provide better answer. GetText from your fields put it into one string use delimeter and  put that data into arraylist shoud not be problem

Comment: I made all changes needed

Comment: side question: what is UserManeger class ? is it predefined one or you made it

Comment: i added UserManager class in the code

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted above, you're not adding your new user to the UserManager. Your line `add(u2);` in signupButtonListener tries to add the user to the frame, not to the UserManager. In fact, the only code that adds a User to an ArrayList is what's hard-coded in the UserManager constructor.

You need to add a method to UserManager that takes a User as a parameter and adds that User to the ArrayList if they're not already in there (you might also want a method that removes a given User if they're already in the ArrayList as well). Then, upon the user signing up, call that method to add the User.

Comment: i have implemented this method on UserManager:
public void addUser(User p)
  if(!userList.contains(p))
   userList.add(p);
  
and in signupButtonListener i have written :userList.addUser(u1) but it says to me userList can not be resolved...

Comment: The class signupButtonListener doesn't have an instance of the userList - and it shouldn't either. You should be using your existing UserManager's addUser() method for all adding of users. You'll probably want to search Wikipedia for the singleton pattern to use on your UserManager class.

Answer (score 0):

---

**1) For the placeOrder Button :**

---

.  **A)** Change it to be static ; to access it from loginFrame class .

```
      static JButton placeOrderButton;
```

.  **B)** modify the actionPerformed method in loginButtonListener class as follows :

```
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        String givenID = usernameField.getText();
        if(userManager.isUserInList(givenID)){
            String givenPass = password.getText();
            User theUser = userManager.getUserWithID(givenID);
            if(givenPass.equals(theUser.getPassword())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access granted!");
                dispose();
                MainFrame.placeOrderButton.setEnabled(true); //her we enable editing
                //  new MainFrame(); no need for that 
            }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Wrong Password",  "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username","Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

---

**2) For adding users to userList(Array List):**

---

.   **A)** Change it to be static ; to access it from SignUpFrame class .

```
      static ArrayList<User> userList;
```

.  **B)** modify SignUpFrame class as follows :

```
      public class SignUpFrame extends JFrame{


           private JButton signupButton;
           private JTextField name;
           private JTextField email;
           private JTextField username;
           private JPasswordField pass;

           //private UserManager userManager; no need for user manager 

           public SignUpFrame (){
                super("Please fill in your Data");

                //userManager = new UserManager(); no need for user manager 

                signupButton = new JButton("Sign Up!");
                signupButton.addActionListener(new signupButtonListener());


                // You were declaring them again !
                 name = new JTextField(15);

                 email = new JTextField(15);

                 username = new JTextField(15);

                 pass = new JPasswordField(15);



                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

                mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

                mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
                mainPanel.add(name);
                mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
                mainPanel.add(email);
                mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
                mainPanel.add(username);
                mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
                mainPanel.add(pass);
                mainPanel.add(signupButton);

                this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
                this.pack();
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setVisible(true);

         }
     class signupButtonListener implements ActionListener{
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           try{ 
              // Organizing for better readability 
              String newName = name.getText();
              String newEmail = email.getText();
              String newUserName = username.getText();
              String newPass = pass.getText();

              User u2 = new User(newName,newEmail,newUserName,newPass);

              UserManager.userList.add(u2);


          }catch(NullPointerException e){
          System.out.println("fill all fields");
           }
               dispose(); //to close SignUpFrame
   }
}
```

Comment: glad that helped :) , the last line is updated to dispose the signup frame.